# How to use POST method in Python's Request Module? (Or how to bypass 414 error in Python web method)

Tags: python, html, http

I have the following code:

```
import requests
password="xxxx"
username="sooo27x"
final_url = "http://targetmine.nibio.go.jp/enrich/analysis/enrichment?theme=Integrated+Pathway+Cluster&dataSet=&taxonId=10090&cutOff=1.00&useSymbol=true&list=Ssb,Eny2,Hsp90b1,Ube3a,Cry1,Prkaa1,Gm4024,Gm4024,Tm9sf2,Ddx5,Hspa8,Rbm26,Btf3,Ppp1cb,Ywhae,Wdr92,Zbtb1,Rc3h2,Hnrnpa2b1,Cnn3,Ccdc59,Minpp1,Gm21399,Shfm1,Gm21399,Mbtps2,Ly75,Pdcl3,Pphln1,Serpinb6b,Txndc9,Mapk1ip1l,Cox17,Psmb4,Seh1l,Mrpl11,Alas1,Mrpl52,Mrpl52,Mrpl52,Ssr3,Arcn1,Grb2,Ufm1,Manf,Nus1,LOC100505064,LOC100505064,Morf4l2,Nus1,Mmp19,Frzb,Slc39a1,Fus,Vma21,Ergic2,Hif1a,Gm13363,Odc1,Odc1,Ap1g1,Agfg1,Agfg1,Agfg1,Slc16a1,Ctps,Ak4,Orc4,Stat5a,Ube2d3,Gale,Sec61a1,Sar1a,Smc1a,Alkbh1,Arih2,Slc31a1,Lrrc59,Vmp1,Id2,Ppp2r3d,Wipf2,Chd1,Piga,Foxp3,Trak1,Snf8,Ctsz,Efhd2,Efhd2,Erp44,2810403A07Rik,Calr,Vamp3,Gm6747,Tmem30a,Rab1,Glis3,Chsy1,Ndufs4,Trim47,9430038I01Rik,Csnk2b,Hars,Grpel1,Psmd2,Uqcrc1,Sf3b2,Kdm1a,Rnps1,Zc3h10,Cnot7,Usp16,Hspa9,Rpl7l1,Srsf1,Uspl1,Sltm,Adnp2,Zfp451,Rbbp5,Cul4b,Smek1,Smad2,Cops3,Qrich1,Shq1,2310036O22Rik,Ngdn,Zcchc9,Eif4a1,Eif4a1,Ankrd28,Yrdc,Bzw1,Bzw1,Gmps,Rars,Zc3h15,Spata5,Eif4a3,Smu1,Nufip1,Ubap2l,Polr2c,Gm9840,Psmb4,Faim,Copg1,Gm6750,Anapc10,Senp6,Asun,Azin1,Dhps,Med19,Kansl2,Mrfap1,Plrg1,Hn1l,Mrpl44,Ssb,Cdc25a,Dnajc21,Emc4,Snrnp27,Gas5,Nmt1,Ppp3cb,Slc25a5,Hax1,Vdac2,Pcna,Smarca5,Hnrnpab,Cct2,Serbp1,Srsf2,Hspe1,Psmc3,Mcts1,Ube2k,Usp10,Mrpl35,Elp2,Mrpl47,Bccip,Pibf1,Pih1d1,Adrm1,Pigf,Phb2,Ube2a,Ik,2610005L07Rik,Msi2,Pdcd2l,Lsm14a,Trnt1,Esf1,Mettl6,Surf6,Rps24,Taf7,Pus3,Trmt10c,Utp23,Atf4,Tmem185b,Tgoln1,Cdk12,Hivep3,Btg3,Appbp2,2410004B18Rik,D8Ertd82e,Rbm17,Taf9,Mrpl3,Ssbp1,Dnajc8,Ccr7,Knop1,Smndc1,Eif5,Krr1,Eif5,Snhg6,Spata5,Eif2s2,Gnl3,Hnrnpd,Seh1l,Rbmxl1,Eif2s1,Trim44,Caprin1,Ythdf2,Vprbp,Srsf6,Gnl2,Dnttip2,Bzw1,Smu1,Tomm20,Srsf2,Srsf2,Taf5l,Eef1d,Mcm3,Umps,Sept2,Ugp2,Dynll2,Krcc1,Vbp1,Rala,Fam96b,Atxn7l3,LOC100044900,Hsp90aa1,Mat2a,Hsp90aa1,Cacybp,Hsp90ab1,Hsp90aa1,Pfdn2,Ngdn,Abl2,Eif1,Srsf11,Ndufb7,Api5,Serbp1,Caprin1,Iws1,Cntd1,Sf1,Tle3,Hnrnpa2b1,Slc7a6os,Hnrnpa2b1,Rsrc2,Becn1,Hdlbp,3110043O21Rik,Rexo4,Ccnt1,Top1,Gm6910,Tbkbp1,Kcnj15,Ly6k,Kpna6,Rpl7l1,Tnfrsf11a,Inip,Cnpy3,Pop1,Simc1,Dtx2,D11Wsu47e,Tfe3,Ttll4,Drg1,Desi1,Gtpbp10,Carm1,Mrpl55,Cbx5,Gclc,Dnttip2,Dnajc21,Ppig,Riok1,Azin1,Pde12,Pin1,Thumpd1,A430005L14Rik,Odc1,Nmd3,Rnmt,Eif3j1,Eif3j1,Eif3j1,Nup54,Nmd3,Metap2,Eif4e,Etf1,Etf1,Gtpbp4,Srfbp1,Dnajc11,Mak16,LOC100045968,Aimp2,Psmb5,Psme3,Timm23,Brix1,Eif3g,Hars,Ipo7,Eif3c,Magoh,Emg1,Pgk1,U2af1,Set,Mrpl3,Nol8,Kti12,Farsb,Nop14,Nars,Fam136a,LOC100045968,Nip7,Ddx18,Utp18,Ddx21,Strap,Mki67ip,LOC101056577,Larp4,Mrps22,Eif4e,Gm5806,Timm17a,Gm5806,Riok2,Dph3,Ywhag,Gtf2f2,Ddx54,Isg20l2,Eed,Canx,LOC100045999,LOC100045999,Rad23b,Gm12952,Gnl2,Dcun1d5,Eif3a,Ddx27,Gm12693,Eif4g2,Eif3a,Cd82,Wdr55,Rcc1,Pop7,Mea1,Pfdn4,Nhp2,Mrps7,Erh,Prmt1,Nasp,Mrps12,Ergic1,Nup205,Rnmtl1,Otud4,Nol9,Bysl,Noc3l,Emc6,Utp15,B3galt6,Bysl,Ube2v2,Arpp19,Gm10349,Ddx39,Ddx39,Ndufab1,Hspd1,Cct8,Anp32b,Utp15,Gspt1,Cct4,Ndufab1,Ppat,Ppan,Rrp1b,Ifrd2,Rpf2,Ruvbl1,Lyar,Gemin6,Dkc1,Nop58,Naa15,Mpp6,Csnk2a1,Cops7a,Nop2,Nolc1,Nudt5,Nudc,Mrpl15,Rrp1b,Rbm34,Rsl24d1,Trmt10a,Heatr6,Ppat,Eif2s2,Ncl,Yae1d1,Mthfd2,Mthfd2,Nop56,Eef1e1,Eif2s2,Slc25a33,Batf,Asns,Nup54,Atf6,Larp4,Naf1,Ndufaf4,Wdr36,Znhit6,Hax1,Zfp593,Slc7a5,Nars,Tars,Ebna1bp2,Mir17hg,Dhx33,Rrp1b,Cirh1a,Dis3,Chchd4,LOC101056577,Srm,Tmem183a,Sf3a2,Pelp1,Cdv3,Psmd11,Trub2,Zfp593,Tti1,Zfp143,Dido1,Caap1,Zbtb21,Srsf10,Prpf38b,Mat2a,Srsf3,Seh1l,Mat2a,Sbno1,Cdc73,U2surp,Ywhae,Hnrnpm,Csnk2a2,Ubxn2a,Grwd1,Tfrc,Cdv3,Kpnb1,Hnrnpu,2900097C17Rik,Eif2s3x,Polr1c,Trim27,Gnpnat1,Srsf1,Syncrip,Urb2,Ilf2,Wdr3,Rps19bp1,Haus6,Yars2,Krr1,Mat2a,Rbm34,Otud4,Mrpl13,Ndufa12,Rnps1,Ddx39,Pam16,Mat2a,Aebp2,Ampd2,Foxk2,Usp31,Mtdh,Amd1,Pmpca,Pogk,Gfpt1,Pole4,Kdm2b,Cd2bp2,l7Rn6,Snx3,Exoc3,Prcc,Bub3,Cdc5l,Ube2g1,Nxt1,Chtf8,Psmd5,Srpk1,Sf3b4,Ubap2l,Mettl25,l7Rn6,Ndufaf6,Prpf3,Nup62,Mtdh,Trap1,Ergic1,Nup133,9130401M01Rik,Edf1,Luc7l,Fkbp4,Rad23a,LOC100862456,Atf6,Anapc10,Ntmt1,1110004E09Rik,Nudt19,Dnpep,Metap1,Gadd45gip1,D10Wsu52e,Rabggtb,Utp11l,Rbm28,Psmc2,Skiv2l2,Txnl1,Sf3a3,Eif2s3x,Cops5,Snrpb,Ddx10,Cyc1,Exosc9,Rpf2,Rnps1,Gm14277,Mrpl19,Mrpl19,Pole4,Dimt1,Edf1,Mrps15,Hypk,Psmd11,Ccdc124,Btf3l4,Ilf2,Eftud2,Ssrp1,Exosc2,Snrnp40,Mrpl21,Rnaseh1,Naa15,Dus4l,4632404H12Rik,Telo2,Simc1,Ccdc137,Umps,Amd1,Pbdc1,LOC634555,Smyd5,Nol11,Lzic,2210016F16Rik,Ppp3cb,Papola,Ppp1r14b,Api5,Mettl4,Coq5,Gid4,D030056L22Rik,Purb,Ptrh2,Dynll2,Tmem168,Cebpg,Ddx31,Kif3b,Sigmar1,2310057M21Rik,Fancf,Ttc30a1,Arl14ep,Gins4,Usp22,Gid8,Dpp8,Ept1,Appbp2,Snapc1,Fam210a,Kpna1,Acbd3,Fbxo28,Fbxo28,Srsf3,Srsf7,Tbp,Uchl5,Zbtb26,Kbtbd8,Selrc1,Ccdc71,2810408M09Rik,Nup54,Phb2,Med29,Nploc4,Gtf2a2,Tbrg4,Rrp9,Prpf4b,Eif2b5,Mesdc2,Tmed9,Fam133b,Orc3,Exosc3,Myg1,Nol12,Sco2,B3galt6,D1Ertd448e,Emd,LOC639905,Pafah1b2,Psip1,Cd8a,Prf1,Cd8a,Cd8a,Tmem51,Hspa1b,Dnajb1,Dnajb1,Wtap,Dnaja1,Dnaja1,Tmem33,Dnaja1,Aldh1l2,Lpp,Chordc1,Hsph1,Hsph1,Mrps6,Mrps6,St13,Stip1,Ahsa1,Ddit3,Mtf1,Ywhah,Tceb3,Cep104,Xab2,Bmper,Col4a3bp,Pcmt1,Marveld2,Zkscan1,Blzf1,Gltpd1,Pigm,Polr3f,Zbtb7a,Phf20,Cdca4,Naa30,Srek1,AI503316,Gimap9,Tdrd3,Eif4ebp2,Sfr1,Nucks1,Mrpl18,Sp1,Prpf4b,Mfsd5,Tsn,Mina,Mocs3,Tatdn2,Toe1,Socs6,Hspa13,Gm2701,Gtf2e2,Pvr,Lin7c,Ccdc127,Ubqln1,Ppp6c,Ing5,Clp1,Tmed7,Derl2,Rab43,C1qb,C1qb,Khdrbs1,Copb2,Gtf3c5,Nkap,Rbm15b,Dhx36,2310044G17Rik,Ppp2r1b,Pigm,Ing5,Srfbp1,Fasn,Fem1a,Dhrs7b,Tsg101,Jmjd6,Tubb4b,Gpn2,Prkcsh,Zfp207,Tagln2,Fam220a,Nln,Cdca4,Celf1,Scaf4,Zbtb25,Mapkapk5,Tti2,Tbrg4,Eif2s2,Psmg3,Chl1,Psmc2,Yme1l1,Rbm25,Immt,Ubtf,Ksr1,Rrad,Pvr,Senp5,Ewsr1,Snrnp70,Acin1,Rab43,Usp7,Pdcd6ip,Mapkapk3,Klrc1,Pknox1,Mgea5,Sympk,Snapc4,Ep400,Farsa,Cdkn2a,Uck2,Hcfc1,Mier2,Ggta1,Naa35,Tmem88b,Zfp865,Scrn3,Napg,Brat1,Kpna1,Fbxw2,Ankrd66,Sp1,Csnk2a1,Gemin5,Mga,Ubxn2a,Usp37,Cdk12,Ncf1,Ncf1,Ptger4,Thap1,Cacul1,Zdhhc5,Col9a3,Lcat,Creb1,Prss36,Ddx49,Bdp1,Clcn7,Itgal,Brip1,Eif3h,D14Ertd426e,Ikbkb,Eef1a2,Gid4,Dcaf8,Tubb3,Coq6,Zfp202,Itfg2,Kif1a,Eme2,Ccng1,Nadk,Ikbke,Otud3,Reg2,Nsa2,Angptl6,Gpatch3,Dgat2,Dgat2,Fitm2,Phf15,Gm12816,Wdr46,Peo1,Snhg1,Snhg1,Huwe1,Ccdc86,2810004N23Rik,Cdk11b,Luc7l,Luc7l,Sema7a,Gtf2f1,D2Wsu81e,Lrp11,Mecr,Psme3,Xpo4,Polr1a,Rabl3,Caprin1,Uchl5,Cebpz,Rwdd4a,Cse1l,Nol8,Noc2l,Tsr1,Rbm27,Cand1,Eif5b,Dnajc2,Ints5,Dcaf13,Tmem11,Atf1,Krr1,Cct6a,Gm9769,Naa15,Rbm8a,Cct3,Ywhae,Gm9769,Cct6a,Zzz3,Api5,Psmc6,Mrpl11,Timm50,Timm44,Trmt1,Tbrg4,Hnrpdl,Mrps27,Dnajc27,Polr3d,Gnb2l1,Gpatch4,Trmt61a,Bop1,Prpf31,Pvt1,Yars,Ttc27,Cct3,Cct3,Pes1,Pus7l,Elp5,Sf3b3,Wdr74,Rnps1,Rcl1,Pprc1,Ssrp1,Tcerg1,G3bp1,Tsr1,Wdr61,Grwd1,Pwp2,2810004N23Rik,D19Bwg1357e,Ddx21,Ikbkap,Heatr1,Pdcd11,Eme2,Rps27l,Eef1d,Gm3244,Gm6415,Nup107,Anapc15,Hprt,Pus1,Dars,Immt,Psma6,Psma6,Psmb3,Mrpl23,Polr2l,Polr3e,Dph5,Rpl12,Timm10,Aprt,Lig3,Dph2,Acsl5,Bre,Nsun5,Pvt1,Zfr,Mrm1,Eme2,Mtor,Rif1,Cox10,Rps17,Rps17,Cpsf1,Bre,Irak1bp1,Supt3,Dus4l,Pkm,Snd1,Mettl1,Cops7a,Wdr18,Polr1a,1700071K01Rik,Ipo4,Gart,Mettl1,Atp5k,Trmt1,Kcnq5,Nif3l1,Bid,Tnpo1,Mipep,Focad,Cox10,BC026590,Tbl3,Dph5,Fbl,Pebp1,Nop10,Mrpl11,Apex1,Nle1,Prmt3,Taf1d,Usp36,Gm5481,Gas5,Rps25,5730408K05Rik,Gm10736,Gas5,B3galt6,Tcam1,Dhx33,Hnrnpa1,Exosc1,Mrpl15,2410002F23Rik,Polr1d,Prmt3,Psmd11,Exosc8,Eif3c,Hspa4,Psmd14,Polr1d,Eif3d,Polr1d,Pole3,Mtch2,Ergic1,Pwp1,Eif3b,Ftsj3,Nkrf,Nsun2,Iars,Iars,Rrp12,Eif5a,Qtrtd1,Snhg1,Snhg1,Grwd1,Polr1e,Psmg1,Got1,Polr1b,Mrps18b,Gm5633,Eif1ax,Wdr36,Pus7,LOC101056547,Prmt3,Cdc34,Prmt5,Rsl1d1,Tomm40,Supv3l1,Gm10349,Mybbp1a,Slc19a1,Aimp2,Rrs1,Gar1,Nhp2,Dkc1,Ddx39,C1qbp,Fbl,Gas5,Bcl2l11,Cisd1,Mrps5,Dnaja3,Zfp598,Gtdc1,Mtdh,Siah2,Gstcd,Siah2,Atf6,Nrp,Gcn1l1,Heatr1,1810032O08Rik,Bid,LOC100047753,Anapc15,Shmt2,Bola3,Hsd17b12,Hsd17b12,Mrps10,Psmb6,Mrpl17,Nubp1,Wbscr22,Prickle4,Dhx9,Ap2b1,Magt1,Glrx2,Gtf3c6,Rpp14,Snrpd3,Fbxo31,Pvt1,Psmd9,Htt,Ptplb,Pinx1,Alg3,Akap1,Ubfd1,Nfkbia,Nfkbia,Nfkbia,Sf3b3,Pabpc1,Rars2,Aen,Cpsf7,Rbm25,Gpt2,Gpt2,Gpt2,Farsa,Noc2l,Sdad1,Gpatch4,Aen,Aen,1810032O08Rik,Elac2,Prpf4,Nol10,Btaf1,Ube2f,Ube2f,Eif6,Ube2f,Ptpn2,LOC101056616,Rab10,Pdss1,Noc4l,Mtap,Slc3a2,Nsun4,Rpp14,Tmem70,2310076G05Rik,Plagl2,Abcf1,Slc31a2,Rbm25,Marcks,Penk,Hnrnpa1,Aldh1a2,Ikzf4,Col4a1,Col4a2,Col4a1,Basp1,Marcks,Marcks,Gpr85,Bak1,Rai14,Ube2f,Serpinb9,Klhdc4,Taf1a,Nsfl1c,Rbm25,Txlng,Mrpl15,Mllt6,Zfp811,Nup85,Ccdc116,Gart,Myo19,Pcgf6,D3Ertd740e,BC023969,Rpl11,Arv1,Mettl2,Atr,Abce1,Tgs1,Timm9,2700038G22Rik,Qtrtd1,Cct4,Il10,Aoah,D10Wsu52e,Hspa9,Snx4,Api5,Acvr1,Rpe,Psip1,Lrrtm2,Bspry,Sae1,Cstf2,Nup54,Prpf40a,Srrm1,Mtpn,Immt,Nrip1,LOC101056574,Zfp446,Cstf2,Slc39a6,Ssrp1,Mad2l2,Gemin5,Lsg1,Ddx56,Gtf2f1,Ddx10,Kctd5,Cdc5l,Pak1ip1,Sf3a3,Rad23a,Pdap1,Eif3a,Plxnc1,Csnk2a1,Csnk2a1,Dzip3,Atic,Syncrip,Mettl16,Ubxn1,Ssb,Rbm25,A130010J15Rik,Cdh22,Cdv3,Zfp458,E130012A19Rik,Armc8,Hsp90b1,Bcl6,Wee1,Sart3,Rnf214,Zfyve19,Rftn1,Lipt1,Agk,Pdzd11,Atp5o,Tmem209,Cox5b,Mrps21,Atp5e,Ndufa7,Cox7c,Coa3,Uqcr10,Trnt1,Lsm12,Pggt1b,Pus10,Wdr89,Tfb1m,A130010J15Rik,Sec23ip,Wdr4,Pmpca,Rnf126,Szrd1,Abcf2,Poglut1,Trmt10a,Plxnc1,Plxnc1,Mre11a,Hspe1,Rcc2,Cct7,Thoc6,Psmg4,Mrpl14,Pom121,Parg,Qtrt1,Spata5l1,Nudt9,Ece2,Alkbh1,Atl3,Atr,Erap1,Tgs1,Dot1l,Ltv1,Wdr43,Ccdc86,Etf1,Ccdc86,Psmd7,Mtap,Gpatch4,Mtap,Kars,Utp6,Cct3,Tgs1,Bcl2a1a,Tma16,Ercc8,Mtx1,5430416N02Rik,Pfkl,Tmem183a,Plagl2,Elac2,Nus1,Ddx54,Naa15,Nol8,Mphosph10,Gtpbp4,Ncl,Nolc1,Zcrb1,Slc7a1,Slc7a1,Ercc6l2,Esf1,Larp4,Commd1,Mettl2,Mettl2,Snhg1,Snhg12,Polr1a,Cars,Aars,Aars,Cct4,Ddx18,Cct2,Cct7,Tcp1,Mars,Mrps28,Mif,Ranbp1,Gm5848,Gm3837,Ncl,Cct5,Gm10349,Ndufa12,Mybbp1a,Nop56,C1qbp,Cbx1,Gm14680,Rcc2,Slc25a5,Dtymk,Xpo1,Xpo1,Piezo1,Ap3s2,Afg3l2,Ints5,Tut1,Sephs1,Ccdc9,Gfm2,Gabpa,Plagl2,Pfkp,St6galnac4,Pfkp,Magohb,Nudt19,Ebag9,Armc8,Txndc17,Txndc17,Atad1,Tomm70a,Tomm70a,Rab10,Rab10,Fcf1,Cyb5b,Caprin1,Psma3,Psmb2,Psma7,Psma5,Hmga1,Mrpl46,Arl5a,Gfm1,Pphln1,Hspbp1,Srsf10,Tcea1,Scfd1,Rpl27a,Wbp4,Fbxo4,Mrpl44,Rangap1,Med1,Smg1,Armc6,AU022252,Nub1,Gm10015,Scaf11,Thoc3,Psmd13,LOC101055731,Ddx18,Efcab2,Lrrc47,Sema7a,Ddx19a,Csnk1d,Armc8,Ndufaf5,2410018M08Rik,Mrps34,LOC101056348,Btf3,Fdx1l,Gnb1,Lrrc41,1110004F10Rik,Eif4e2,Mapre1,Polr2m,Txnl4a,Mrpl38,Rrp7a,Ier3ip1,Senp2,Snrnp35,Bcl2l11,Mettl22,Ppie,C3ar1,C3ar1,C3ar1,Fgfbp3,Fcgr4,Neb,Cd70,Taf15,Igsf8,Pvr,Otud4,Apol7a,Tmcc3,Mrpl13,Mei4,Ddx6,Il12b,Il12b,Tmem39a,Fscn1,Fscn1,Ddx55,Pogk,Mcm9,Nudcd3,Adap1,Nfkbib,Tbc1d8,Relb,Suds3,Traf2,Il2ra,Traf1,LOC100653389,Gadd45b,Gadd45b,Pcdh19,Hk2,Ghitm,Rnf4,Cstf3,Tmem68,Ctage5,Fscn1,Nck2,Traf1,Aebp2,Rnf115,Rnf115,Cdh17,Amigo2,1500012F01Rik,Tubb2b,Fam129a,Fam89a,Rad51ap1,Rad51,Hells,Gins1&showBg=false"
r = requests.get(final_url,auth=(username,password))
print r.text
```

Which prints:

```
In [33]: print r.text
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>414 Request-URI Too Large</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Request-URI Too Large</h1>
<p>The requested URL's length exceeds the capacity
limit for this server.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (Scientific Linux) Server at sagace.nibio.go.jp Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Note that it prints 414 error. My question is that how can I do POST method in [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) to overcome this problem? Other solution other than [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html) also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`requests.post()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#make-a-request) instead of `requests.get()` and move your parameters into form-encoded data. For example, instead of having `theme=Integrated+Pathway+Cluster` in the URL, do

```
payload = {
     'theme': 'Integrated+Pathway+Cluster'
}
requests.post(final_url, data=payload)
```

(remove the `theme` parameter from the URL). You may have do this same procedure with lots of the parameters in the URL until the error is resolved.

Comment: Thanks but why it still gives 414 error? Any way to bypass that?